# The data is not inserted correctly in the table tbody tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem setting the body in the dynamic content table.

In fact, thead has been set correctly, but most likely the problem is the tbody; the header of the columns is perfectly displayed, but the content is not.

**See image below** (*Nessun dato presente nella tabella --> No data in the table*)

Can anyone kindly help me?

```js
var allart = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(allart);
                var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
                allart.Items.forEach(function (item) {               
                    let child = document.createElement("tr");
                    child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.titolo}</td>
                    <td>${item.marca}</td>
                    <td>${item.immagine}</td> 
                    <td>${item.sezione}</td>
                    <td>${item.data}</td>
                    `;
                    table.appendChild(child);
                })
                tbdy.appendChild(tr);
                table.appendChild(tbdy);
                
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#my-table').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
            });
            $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
        });
```

```html
<table id="my-table" class="row-border hover" width="90%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-sm">Id</th>
                <th class="th-sm">Titolo</th>
                <th class="th-sm">Marca</th>
                <th class="th-sm">Immagine</th>
                <th class="th-sm">Sezione</th>
                <th class="th-sm">Data</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
```

Comment: datatables has its own rendering api (https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html), your most likely encountering a race condition on the finishing of the ajax call and rending the table and document ready

Comment: Replace `table.appendChild(child);` with `document.querySelector('table').appendChild(tbody);` and the creation outside the loop.`tbody.append.appendChild(child);` and remove the other two expressions that are outside the `.forEach()`

Comment: @zer00ne Can you answer with an answer?

Comment: Does console log a waning that `table` object doesn't exist?

Comment: @zer00ne no. it doesn't give me any errors

Comment: Ok @elfuso please post an example of what 2 rows of data might look like .

Comment: @zer00ne Here is the example.: https://jsfiddle.net/2z350d7b/1/ . Here are the results. I hope you will help me because I am going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append tr with tbody inside the loop.

```
allart.Items.forEach(function (item) {
    let child = document.createElement("tr");
    child.innerHTML = `
                <td>${item.id}</td>
                <td>${item.titolo}</td>
                <td>${item.marca}</td>
                <td>${item.immagine}</td> 
                <td>${item.sezione}</td>
                <td>${item.data}</td>
                `;
    tbdy.appendChild(child);
})
table.appendChild(tbdy);
```

Comment: The elements are there, but the message No data in the table still appears. It appears that they are not inserted in the table. Now the message appears above the items, not below like the image I showed you earlier